# Parsing through a pandas Dataframe and applying rules based on different conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, missing-data

I have a made up dataframe to replicate the real problem I am trying to work through in python in reconciling account rates held on mainframe system to what they should be set to from rates tables.

I have 3 tables but they have been merged into one dataframe for this example.

1. Account Information with Interest Rate Conditions (first 5 columns of df). These rates are the actual rates applied to the accounts and need to be matched off to ensure they were set up correctly
2. Non Std Rates - Certain accounts will apply these non-std rates once certain conditions are met
3. Std Rates- Same as above these will apply once certain conditions are met

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame([[1234567890,3.5,'GG','N','N','Y',np.NaN,np.NaN,'N','N',3.5,'GG'],
                    [7854567890,np.NaN,'GG','N','N','N',np.NaN,'GG','N','N',3.5,'GG'],
                    [9876542190,3.5,'FF','N','N','Y',np.NaN,np.NaN,'N','Y',3.5,'FI'],
                    [9632587415,3.5,'GG','N','N','N',3,'GG','N','N',3.5,'GG']],
columns = ['Account','Account_Spread','Account_Swing','indict_1','indict_2','Negotiated_Rate',
           'Non_std_Spread','Non_std_Code','Non_std_indict_1','Non_std_indict_2','Std_Spread','Std_Swing'])
df
```

Conditions:

- Account Data (Account Spread and Account Swing) should only be matched against the non-std rates if columns "**Non_std_Spread**" or "**Non_std_Code**" or both are populated and the "**Negogiated_Rate**" column is set to **N**.
- Account Data (Spread and Swing) should only be matched against the std rates if columns "**Non_std_Spread**" or "**Non_std_Code**" are both null and the "**Negogiated_Rate**" column is set to **N** or **Y**.
- for those accounts where the above indicator is set to **Y**, the indicator in the non-std data "**Non_std_indict_1**"and "**Non_std_indict_2**" need to be compared to "**indict_1**" and "**indict_2**" respectively and report matches and mismatches.

The Desired Outcome:

- A new column added to dataframe identifying if a match or mismatch was detected comparing the account spread and code to either its equivalent in the non-std rates or std rates. Something like "**MatchOnNSR**" or "**MismatchOnSR**".
- Another column or columns comparing if a mismatch occurred between the indicator columns when the Negogiated_Rate was flagged as Y

Sample Output with expected results:

```
df=pd.DataFrame([[1234567890,3.5,'GG','N','N','Y',np.NaN,np.NaN,'N','N',3.5,'GG','MatchOnSR',True,True],
                    [7854567890,np.NaN,'GG','N','N','N',np.NaN,'GG','N','N',3.5,'GG','MatchOnNSR',np.NaN,np.NaN],
                    [9876542190,3.5,'FF','N','N','Y',np.NaN,np.NaN,'N','Y',3.5,'FI','MismatchOnSR',True,False],
                    [9632587415,3.5,'GG','N','N','N',3,'GG','N','N',3.5,'GG','MismatchOnSNR',np.NaN,np.NaN]],
columns = ['Account','Account_Spread','Account_Swing','indict_1','indict_2','Negotiated_Rate',
           'Non_std_Spread','Non_std_Code','Non_std_indict_1','Non_std_indict_2','Std_Spread','Std_Swing','Is_Match','Match_indict_1','Match_indict_2'])
df
```

At present I don't have anything to share to work this problem out. I'm struggling to know what the best approach would be to get even started. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Will you please share a dataframe that you want to get? That makes it easier to visual the conditions.

Comment: here you go. i have added the extra columns with the expected results:

Comment: <strike>Did you? I don't see a recent edit in the post.</strike> Nevermind. Saw it now.

Comment: I think you want `DataFrame.assign` along with `numpy.select`

Comment: I've got an almost-working solution, but I'm stumped by something: `Non_std_Spread` row #2 is NaN but `Non_std_Code` #2 is **not** NaN. Is that a mistake? Your specs imply that both should either be NaN or not NaN.

Comment: From reviewing the actual real data I have, there are many instances where Non_std_Spread is NaN and Non_std_Code  is not.

Comment: Ok, that's fine. But what should `Is_Match` be in such a case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer is a response to some version related issues raised in my other one*

You could try using masks thereby 'cond_...', something like:

```
cond_nan = df['Non_std_Spread'].isna() & df['Non_std_Code'].isna()

df.loc[cond_nan,'match_indict_1'] = df.loc[cond_nan,'indict_1'] == df.loc[cond_nan,'Non_std_indict_1']
df.loc[cond_nan,'match_indict_2'] = df.loc[cond_nan,'indict_2'] == df.loc[cond_nan,'Non_std_indict_2']
df.loc[cond_nan,'Is_Match'] = np.where(
    (df.loc[cond_nan,'Account_Spread'] == df.loc[cond_nan,'Std_Spread']) & (df.loc[cond_nan,'Account_Swing'] == df.loc[cond_nan,'Std_Swing']),
    "MatchOnSR", "MismatchOnNSR",
)


cond_no_nan = ~df['Non_std_Spread'].isna() & ~df['Non_std_Code'].isna() & (df['Negotiated_Rate'] == 'N')

df.loc[cond_no_nan,'Is_Match'] = np.where(
    (df.loc[cond_no_nan,'Account_Spread'] == df.loc[cond_no_nan,'Non_std_Spread']) & (df.loc[cond_no_nan,'Account_Swing'] == df.loc[cond_no_nan,'Non_std_Code']),
    "MatchOnSR", "MismatchOnNSR",
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it:

```py
def compute_match(row):
    m = match_indict_1 = match_indict_2 = np.nan

    if row['Non_std_Spread'] == 'nan' and row['Non_std_Code'] == 'nan':
        match_indict_1 = row['indict_1'] == row['Non_std_indict_1']
        match_indict_2 = row['indict_2'] == row['Non_std_indict_2']
        if row['Account_Spread'] == row['Std_Spread'] and row['Account_Swing'] == row['Std_Swing']:
            m = 'MatchOnSR'
        else:
            m = 'MismatchOnSR'

    elif row['Non_std_Spread'] != 'nan' and row['Non_std_Code'] != 'nan' and row['Negotiated_Rate'] == 'N':
        match_indict_1 = match_indict_2 = np.nan
        if row['Account_Spread'] == row['Non_std_Spread'] and row['Account_Swing'] == row['Non_std_Code']:
            m = 'MatchOnNSR'
        else:
            m = 'MismatchOnNSR'

    return (m, match_indict_1, match_indict_2)


df = (
    pd.concat([
        df,
        (
            df
            .fillna('nan')
            .apply(compute_match, axis=1, result_type='expand')
            .rename({0:'Is_Match', 1:'Match_indict_1', 2:'Match_indict_2'}, axis=1)
        ),
    ], axis=1)
)
```

Test:

```
      Account  Account_Spread Account_Swing indict_1 indict_2 Negotiated_Rate  Non_std_Spread Non_std_Code Non_std_indict_1 Non_std_indict_2  Std_Spread Std_Swing       Is_Match Match_indict_1 Match_indict_2
0  1234567890             3.5            GG        N        N               Y             NaN          NaN                N                N         3.5        GG      MatchOnSR           True           True
1  7854567890             NaN            GG        N        N               N             NaN           GG                N                N         3.5        GG            NaN            NaN            NaN
2  9876542190             3.5            FF        N        N               Y             NaN          NaN                N                Y         3.5        FI   MismatchOnSR           True          False
3  9632587415             3.5            GG        N        N               N             3.0           GG                N                N         3.5        GG  MismatchOnNSR            NaN            NaN
```

Notice that `Is_Match` row #2 is `NaN` - that's becuse `Non_std_Spread` row #2 is `NaN` but `Non_std_Code` row #2 is **not** `NaN`.

Comment: In the `elif`, `match_indict_1 = match_indict_2 = np.nan` seems superfluous

Comment: Great work to solve the problem......it really is. Do you think its better then to replace the NaN values before doing the analysis so the output results won't have a NaN in it like in row 2? My understanding is you can't compare a NaN value with another NaN value to return true....maybe I am wrong.

Comment: You're certainly right @Alan, that's why I added `.fillna('nan')` before processing. But that doesn't affect the original dataset. The processor function gets a datframe containg the string `'nan'` instead of `np.nan`, but only it gets it. The dataframe returned does not have those NaNs. Does that make sense (am I answering your question)?

Comment: It is superflous @hpchavaz, but I left it in because I felt like it aided clarity slightly. Do you disagree?

Comment: @user17242583 Ah yes, I see the .fillna in the concatenation of the dfs. Do you think it would be better that the .fillna('nan') is applied to the original dataset?

Comment: It depends on your usecase, @Alan. You can compare nan by either using `np.isnan(...)` or `pd.isna(...)`, so it's not like you _can't_ check if something is nan. I just used that to reduce the amount of code, 'cause it was already getting a little lengthy :)

Comment: Okay thanks understood. Is there anything else I can try to fix the output from row 2?

Comment: @user17242583, superfluous code should be removed, but you could transform it in a comment if you think that it clarifies example `# Note: here match_indict_1 == and match_indict_2 == np.nan`. IMHO, the comment is not needed.

Comment: @hpchavaz why is it superfluous code? Isn't this line of code used to assign default values to the new variables?

Comment: Yes it is, @Alan, but since those variables were previously declared and initialized with `np.nan`, that will just be re-setting them to `np.nan`, which is effectually pointless.

Answer (score 0):

*This answer raise some version related issues, see comments*

In a pure Pandas way, but not too much idiomatic and may be not so efficient:

```
nandf = df.query("Non_std_Spread.isna() and Non_std_Code.isna()")
nandf["match_indict_1"] = nandf["indict_1"] == nandf["Non_std_indict_1"]
nandf["match_indict_2"] = nandf["indict_2"] == nandf["Non_std_indict_2"]
nandf["Is_Match"] = np.where(
    (nandf["Account_Spread"] == nandf["Std_Spread"]) & (nandf["Account_Swing"] == nandf["Std_Swing"]),
    "MatchOnSR", "MismatchOnNSR",
)

nonandf = df.query("not(Non_std_Spread.isna()) and not(Non_std_Code.isna()) and Negotiated_Rate == 'N'")
nonandf["Is_Match"] = np.where(
    (nonandf["Account_Spread"] == nonandf["Non_std_Spread"]) & (nonandf["Account_Swing"] == nonandf["Non_std_Code"]),
    "MatchOnSR", "MismatchOnNSR",
)

df = nandf.combine_first(df)
df = nonandf.combine_first(df)
```

Comment: I get the following error in line 1  `TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` when executing your code

Comment: @AlanPaul, It runned on my computer, with some warnings not related to the error you cited..But, rightnow under in a Google Colab notebook, I confirm that I get the same error as you. I will try to check  tonight , if there is a typo.

Comment: Great thanks @hpchavaz

Comment: Maybe a version related problem. On the other computer: Python version 3.10.0 / Pandas version 1.3.4 / NumPy version 1.21. 0 and Google Colab: Python version 3.7.12 / Pandas version 1.1.5 / NumPy version 1.19.5

Comment: @AlanPaul: it definitely run under Python version 3.10.0 / Pandas version 1.3.4 / Numpy Version: 1.21.4